# Finding all limit points of a set

Tags: analysis

How can I find all the limit points of this set?

$S=\left\{\frac{x}{2^y} \mid x, y\in  ℕ  , x \leq y\right\}$ with $S \subset ℝ$.

Could this be proved if I showed that $∀δ > 0, \exists z ∈ S\text{ with }0 < |z-z_0| < δ$?

Comment: If you preface it with $\forall z_0$ you will prove the limit points are all of $\Bbb R$, which is true.

Comment: So I cannot get all limit points by using that right?

Comment: Yes, you get them all.  Your set $S$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so its limit points are all of $\Bbb R$.  Proving your final statement for all $z_0$ is what you want.  Intuitively, what it says is that if I give you any $z_0$ and any $\epsilon \gt 0$, you can find a point $z \in S$ that is within $\epsilon$ of $z_0$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Alright thank you :)
I'm not sure how to do it but I will try it somehow using that formula.

Comment: How do you know it is dense in R?  if w in M then w = x/2^y y ge x so 2^y ge 2*x so w le 1/2 so ... um,  I don't see it.  Anything above 1/2 is a distinct difference away.  And all M is positive.  Frankly I think 0 is the only limit point but I'm having a hard time ruling out others.

Comment: Find an Element of m, that is negative, that is larger than 1/2, that is within 1/256 of 3/8. M is not dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were no restriction on the numerator of the fraction, your set $S$ would be dense in $\Bbb R$, so its limit points would be all of $\Bbb R$.  Proving your final statement for all $z_0$ is what you want.  Intuitively, what it says is that if I give you any $z_0$ and any $\epsilon \gt 0$, you can find a point $z \in S$ that is within $\epsilon$ of $z_0$.  Given $z_0, \epsilon,$ you can pick $y$ large enough that $\frac 1 {2^y} \lt \epsilon$, then you can find an $x$ so that $|z_0-\frac x{2^y}| \lt \epsilon$

With the restriction that $x \le y$, the only limit point is zero.  For any $z_0 \gt 0 \text { and } 0 \lt \epsilon \lt z_0$ you can find a $y$ such that $\frac y{2^y} \lt z_0$.  There are only finitely many points in $S$ greater than that $\frac y{2^y},$, so a closest one to $z_0$ (other than $z_0$), so taking an $\epsilon$ small enough will exclude them all and $z_0$ is not a limit point.

Comment: M most certainly is not dense in R. You can find a small enough 1/2^k but the numerator must be less than k, which does not put it anywhere near z.  In fact M $\subset (0,1/2] $ so at best M is dense in [0,1/2] but it isn't that either.

Comment: @fleablood:  I missed the limit on the numerator, so I'll fix it.

Comment: That x/2^y x<=y is a *huge* restriction.  Without it, M is dense in the non-negative reals.  With it... well to get within 1/2^k you must be less than k/2^k which gets closer to zero for large k.

Answer (score 0):

0 is the only limit point.

Notice $1/2 = 2/2^2>3/2^3>...>k/2^k>(k+1)/2^{k+1}>... $.   Thus for any $x>0$ there is a maximal $k/2^k < x $.  The only terms of M larger are $j/2^l $ where $j \le l <k $ so there are only finitely many of these.  Thus x is not a limit point.

All M are positive so so no negative x will be a limit point.

So only possible limit point is 0.

0 is a limit point because for all $\epsilon >0$ we can find $0 <1/2^k <\epsilon $.