# Almost found the limit points of this set

Tags: analysis, limits

I want to find all limit points of the given set, and I think I almost got it.

$M=\left\{\frac{x}{2^y} \mid x, y\in  ℕ  , x \leq y\right\}$ also $M \subset ℝ$.

We say that:

$\forall \delta > 0,\exists z \in S$ with: $0 < |z-z_0| < \delta$
I will take $y$ and give it any high value so that we got $\frac 1 {2^y} \lt \delta$. After, I think I can choose a $z$ so that the inequality stays true: $|z_0-\frac x{2^y}| \lt \delta$.

The only problem is, how can I know what to choose, not quite sure what I can take for $z$. Probably something that is bigger than $\frac 1 {2^y}$? But what exactly?

Comment: The set of limit points  $= M \cup \{0\}$

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this other post from 2 hours ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824802/finding-all-limit-points-of-a-set)...

Comment: I know there isn't much missing, can't anyone give me a hint?

Comment: 0 is the only limit point.  All points of M are between 0 and 1/2.  For any x>0 there is a maximal k/2^k < x.  There are only finitely many points of M greater than the maximal k/2^k so x is not limit point.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for answer! But what I described here is correct so far or not at all?

Comment: Well....  I guess so.  For d very small y might need to be big meaning x/2^y is very small meaning z is very close to zero.  But that's a backwards way to find limit points and I don't think it works in general.